# How can I change the field value in a column to 'other' if the value does not exist in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle database that is not well normalized, so it allows free-form entry in a few fields that should be foreign keyed to a lookup table if designed better. For example an Items table looks like this:

```
TABLE: Items
ID  |   NAME    |   CATEGORY
1       foo         cat1
2       bar         cat2
3       baz         weirdCat
...
```

The business has now decided that there are Approved Categories stored in a table like shown below, and in any query using Category, if the value IS NOT in the approved categories table it should show as 'Other'.

```
TABLE: ApprovedCategories
ID  |   CATEGORY
1       cat1
2       cat2
```

I have figured out how to replace the values using CASE but only if I hard code the category values in my select like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,    
    CASE category
        WHEN 'cat1' THEN category
        WHEN 'cat2' THEN category
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS category 
FROM
    Items;
```

In order to try to link it to the values in ApprovedCategories I have tried several thing like the code below but haven't found anything that works:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,    
    CASE category
        WHEN IN (SELECT category FROM ApprovedCategories) THEN category 
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS category 
FROM
    Items;
```

Note: the requirements do not allow me to just update the values in the items table. I have to retain the original category entries in that table for now, even if they are not in the ApprovedCategory table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a left join to approved category table will be a good way to implement this. If a category does not exist, `a.category` will be null and subsequently replaced by "Other".

```
select coalesce(a.category, 'Other')
  from Items i
  left join ApprovedCategories a on(a.category = i.category);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM ApprovedCategories
        WHERE ApprovedCategories.category = Items.category 
    )
    THEN category
    ELSE 'Other'
END AS category
```

Comment: I wish I could mark both as accepted because this answer works great as well. The team I'm on slightly preferred the left join syntax from Ronnis.